# Rest API to validate external OAuth 2.0 access token

Tags: api, rest, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

Im building rest api (using PHP, Laravel) which is used by mobile applications. The api basically is just commenting system.

Im planning to allow users to log in (to use this api) using their Facebook/MS/Twitter etc accounths using OAuth 2.

Flow would be something like this:

- Authenticate user in mobile client using (user) selected OAuth provider
- Get access_token (also maybe username/email) from OAuth provider and save it to mobile client
- User access my rest Api (leaves comment), I include OAuth auth token to request
- In server side I validate this token

Does this make sense? Is there any better ways to build this kind of system where the actual authentication server is completely different than the resource server?